# Moto g4 play is not eligible for bootloader unlock

Tags: motorola-moto-g

I have a Moto g4 play bought from Amazon (no ads version) and was attempting to open bootloader by finding the device code and plugging it into the site. It is not eligible for bootloader unlock and I am curious why, and if possible, are there any work-arounds? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it a full retail version, or an Amazon version? Look in Settings - About Phone and tell us the Software Channel of your device, and I can likely provide an answer to your question.

Comment: The software channel is "retus". Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually, that's not what I expected... You will need to contact Motorola then if you want to unlock. There are still no work-around or bypass, unlocking can only be done via official methods.

Comment: Thank you! Is that all I need to do? Only call Motorola and request an unlock code?

Comment: No, I never said call... The only way they support unlocking issues is via the office forums. Register and go to your device forum, there should be some pinned post about unlocking issues and follow it's instructions. I wish you luck, 95% if people get no response, most because to they don't read and follow the directions. Motorola under Lenovo is kind of a joke in this area, the reality is you probably will never get this unlocked.

Comment: Ahh I'll try but I thank you alot for this. I hope this does work!